# What is the best way to create/write to a word document using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word

I am trying to create a word document from a python script on windows.  The document that I am creating has one table and a few pages of paragraph.  I want to know how to do this.  Thanks.

Comment: This may get flagged for being too broad. What have you tried so far? Have you searched the web and found anything?

Comment: I have searched the web , what I have found so far is using win32com.client I have tried that and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it's not as simple as writing to a less proprietary filetype, but there are a lot of good options out there. For one, you could try IronPython, which intrinsically has access to all of the Office formats.

However, I would personally recommend this library: https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

Great library for working with docx, but if you want to extend this to working with other Microsoft filetypes I'd look into IronPython or doing some OpenOffice scripting.